# Scala synchornized and volatile decorator not working as expected?

Tags: scala

I am trying to understand if synchronised locks the resource appropriately to get me the correct results for following code:

```
object ThreadsExample extends App {
  private class BankAccount(private var balance:Int = 0) {
    def getAmount:Int = this.balance
    def deposit(amount:Int):Unit = this.synchronized {this.balance += amount}
    def withdraw(amount:Int):Unit = this.synchronized{this.balance -= amount}
  }

  private val newAccount: BankAccount = new BankAccount(2000)

  for(_ <- 1 to 1000) {
    new Thread(() => newAccount.deposit(1)).start()
  }

  for (_ <- 1 to 1000) {
    new Thread(() => newAccount.withdraw(1)).start()
  }

  println(newAccount.getAmount)
}
```

But to my surprise, it outputs: `2001` for 90% of the time and `2000` for 10% of the time. Can someone explain to me why this is happening since I am using `this. synchronized`?

Additionally I tried to use `@volatile` decorator as well but that seemed to have no effect as well:

`private class BankAccount(@volatile private var balance:Int = 0)`

Comment: What do you expect it to print?

Comment: TBH, I would reject any application **Scala** code that looks like this. We have way better tools to manage concurrency than raw looks and memory barriers.

Comment: Yes, I just started learning Akka and for that I was exploring threads and how they're currently working. Nothing of production app, coming from single threaded programming (JS) I am exploring how multi threading operations are managed in Scala and then would move forward

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your main thread prints the state of `newAccount.getAmount` right after it started those 2000 threads. There is no determinism regarding how many of those threads executed their work at that point.

If you want your main thread to print the state of `newAccount.getAmount` after all 2000 threads mutated it, then you need to wait for all threads to finish, e.g. by joining them:

```
object ThreadsExample extends App {
  private class BankAccount(private var balance: Int = 0) {
    def getAmount: Int = this.balance
    def deposit(amount: Int): Unit = this.synchronized {
      this.balance += amount
    }
    def withdraw(amount: Int): Unit = this.synchronized {
      this.balance -= amount
    }
  }

  private val newAccount: BankAccount = new BankAccount(2000)

  val depositThreads = for (_ <- 1 to 1000) yield {
    val t = new Thread(() => newAccount.deposit(1))
    t.start()
    t
  }

  val withdrawThreads = for (_ <- 1 to 1000) yield {
    val t = new Thread(() => newAccount.withdraw(1))
    t.start()
    t
  }

  withdrawThreads.foreach(_.join)
  depositThreads.foreach(_.join)

  println(newAccount.getAmount)
}
```

Comment: that makes perfect sense. Thank you very much @MartinHH for the detailed explanation with code